# ExpressionVisitor not visiting overridden property of a derived class

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

I'm trying to use the `ExpressionVisitor` to get an overridden member of an expression but it's giving me the *base* one. What am I missing here?

The following example reproduces this behaviour:

Simple base and derived types:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual string Property { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override string Property { get; set; }
}
```

I use this expression visitor:

```
internal class DemoVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private MemberInfo _member;

    public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        var visitor = new DemoVisitor();
        visitor.Visit(expression);

        return visitor._member;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        // invalid member here
        //node.Member.DeclaringType.Name.Dump();
        _member = _member ?? node.Member;

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Calling it like that

```
void Main()
{
    var derived = new Derived();
    var expression = (Expression<Func<string>>)(() => derived.Property);
    DemoVisitor.GetMemberInfo(expression).DeclaringType.Name.Dump();
}
```

This returns `Base` instead of `Derived`. What do I have to do to get to the overridden member?

I need it because I'm reading its attributes later and it's currently giving me the attributes of the property on the base class instead of the derived one.

Comment: You use `DeclaringType` meaning you want the the type where the property is declared, which is the base type. Try using `ReflectedType` instead. Also, I think that using an expression visitor for this is overkill as you found just use `(expression.Body as MemberExpession)?.Member`.

Comment: @ckuri I've just check it and dumpled the entire `MemberInfo` there is no trace of the `Derived` class ;-( there is some magic going on... the documentation also does not specify which member is visited by `VisitMember` exactly.

Comment: @ckuri I assure you, this isn't an overkill ;-) it's doing also a few other things but this part didn't work for this case so I created this example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @t3chb0t I do not know enough about the topic at had. But the Obvious magic would be stuff like the Compiler or JiT Compiler cutting out the type, because it is unused. The Optimisations can cause all kinds of issues if you look at stuff at runtime.

Comment: @Christopher I'm pretty sure this is a bug because when I use `visitor._type.GetMember(visitor._member.Name).Single();` to fix the issue based on ckuri's answer I'm getting the correct member. The visitor must be taking the wrong path.

Comment: @Christopher I think this bug is in the expression builder (probably the compiler) because the visitor receives an _invalid_ expression already...

Comment: @t3chb0t: As I already said, this is not my area of Expertise. I just stumbeled over the JiT and other Optimsiation often enough I thought it is worth mentioning.

Comment: @Christopher I reported it as a bug to the [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/357178/invalid-lambdaexpressions-member-for-derived-types.html) - let's see what they say ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the type of the class/struct of your member you need to look at the `MemberExpression`'s Expression property which is the expression for the object containing the member - in your case the `derived` variable - and get its type.

Therefore your visitor needs to return both (here I used a ValueTuple):

```
internal class DemoVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private Type type;
    private MemberInfo _member;

    public static (Type, MemberInfo) GetMemberInfo(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        var visitor = new DemoVisitor();
        visitor.Visit(expression);

        return (visitor.type, visitor._member);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (_member == null)
        {
          _member = node.Member;
          type = node.Expression.Type;
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Regarding your other question about which member gets visited: all used members in your expression get visited, i.e. all methods, properties and fields, whereas node.Member returns either a `MethodInfo`, `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo` object, which all derive from `MemberInfo`.

Comment: oh, this gave me an idea... I check whether the `_type` and `DeclaringType`  are the same and if not I'm fixing it with `visitor._type.GetMember(visitor._member.Name).Single();` - now I'm getting the member I expect ;-)